# Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed in two different namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I use a XSL to display XML, it always gave me error "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."

Don't know which part is wrong, please help.

here is xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="asup.xsl"?>

<T_VSERV xmlns="http://someweb.com/ns/T_VSERV/1.0 
    xmlns:asup="http://someweb.com/ns/ASUP/1.1" >
<asup:TABLE_INFO>
<asup:field>
    <asup:tag>vserver</asup:tag>
    <asup:smf_name>vserver</asup:smf_name>
    <asup:ui_name>Vserver</asup:ui_name>
    <asup:type>vs_text_alt_sort</asup:type>
    <asup:qualification>key</asup:qualification>
    <asup:remap>hash</asup:remap>
</asup:field>
<asup:field>
    <asup:tag>id</asup:tag>
    <asup:smf_name>id</asup:smf_name>
    <asup:ui_name>Id-Unsigned</asup:ui_name>
    <asup:type>unsigned</asup:type>
    <asup:qualification>read</asup:qualification>
    <asup:remap>noop</asup:remap>
</asup:field>
</asup:TABLE_INFO>
</T_VSERV>
```

here is xsl

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://someweb.com/ns/T_AUTOSUPPORT/1.0"
    xmlns:asup="http://someweb.com/ns/ASUP/1.1">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>ASUP</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>tag</th>
      <th>ui_name</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="asup:TABLE_INFO/asup:field'">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="asup:tag"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="asup:ui_name"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Comment: You should test your XSLT at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/. That way you will get a meaningful error message that tells you `Namespace for stylesheet element should be http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but I didn't make the XML, it was already there, all I can do is to create a xsl stylesheet. ...

Comment: Yes, the issue is with the stylesheet. The namespace declaration for the xsl prefix is wrong. It should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. Thanks!

Comment: Also note you have a rogue `:template>` at the end of the stylesheet which should not be there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try This**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:aa="http://someweb.com/ns/T_VSERV/1.0"
    xmlns:asup="http://someweb.com/ns/ASUP/1.1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs aa"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>ASUP</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>tag</th>
                        <th>ui_name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//asup:TABLE_INFO/asup:field">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="asup:tag"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="asup:ui_name"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is just what the comment says: the XSLT namespace is wrong. But also adds some unused namespace declaration... With no explanation this just obfuscated the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works. it seems I need spend some time to ready XPath document. There is no fast-food in coding world.

Answer (score 3):

The stylesheet is invalid because an XSLT stylesheet must be rooted at a `stylesheet` (or transform) element in namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`.

Your wannabe-stylesheet is rooted at a `stylesheet` element in namespace `http://someweb.com/ns/T_AUTOSUPPORT/1.0`, which is incorrect.